# Wrong partition sizes (I think?)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, gpt, parted

I know just enough about Linux to mess things up, so apologies in advance. I have tried looking at some of the other threads here similar to this, but none of the answers seem to help. I have a 4TB Seagate Central drive that I need to get data off, but I am unable to, hoping you can help.

Here is what I have tried so far, I've 'bolded' the commands I entered

**pc1@PC1:/$ sudo parted -l**

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72101 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      257MB   1000GB  1000GB  logical                lvm


Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4249MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4249MB  4249MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  996GB  996GB  ext4
```

pc1@PC1:/$ **sudo gdisk /dev/sdb**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
3472328288413643170 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Command (? for help): **i**
Partition number (1-128): 8
Partition GUID code: E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928 (Linux LVM)
Partition unique GUID: B05189FC-488F-4DED-97F7-0C5E644CF129
First sector: 10569728 (at 5.0 GiB)
Last sector: 7814037134 (at 3.6 TiB)
Partition size: 7803467407 sectors (3.6 TiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Data'

Command (? for help): **v**
Problem: partition 119 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 120 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 121 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 122 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 123 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 124 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 125 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 126 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 127 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 128 is too big for the disk.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
3472328288413643170 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Identified 4281 problems!
```

**sudo fixparts /dev/sdb**

```
(parted) check 8

Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.

(parted) **rescue start**                                                     
Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
```

So this is as far as I can get...which is just far enough for it to keep telling me what is wrong and what to do to fix it, I just don't know how to go about that - it actually seems like it isn't that hard, but I don't want to mess around with it any more at this point b/c I don't know what I am doing. I've checked out the info here -->http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html but don't understand it enough to proceed with confidence - HELP! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, it is a lot easier to read now, sadly, I'm still no further with it :/

Answer (score 1):

Several points about your post make no sense or is confusing:

- You claim you've got a 4TB disk, but the `parted` output you posted shows a 1TB disk. It appears that your 4 TB disk is `/dev/sdb`, but the `parted` output is for `/dev/sda`, with no `/dev/sdb` output shown for `/dev/sda`.
- The `i` command in `gdisk` shows information about an *individual partition,* so that output is irrelevant. The `v` command in `gdisk` verifies the integrity of the entire disk, and that output indicates numerous problems of the sort that seem to imply that the program is working on "garbage," not real data. Based on the warnings at the start of the `gdisk` output, I'd say your GPT data is so badly damaged that it's useless. It might not even be a GPT disk.
- What you've presented as `fixparts` output looks like `parted` output.

Because the information in your question is so confused and incomplete, I recommend you start a *new question* that shows the output of the `fdisk` and `parted` programs on `/dev/sdb` (`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and `sudo parted /dev/sdb print`), since I suspect you may have an MBR disk with some leftover GPT traces on it. Including the `gdisk` program's `v` output might be worth including, but not the `i` output. If I'm right, fixing the MBR data structures may be in order, but you've presented no data that would be helpful in this task, and this site's format doesn't lend itself to such a major re-write of your initial question.